# How to remove dynamically allocated subviews from scrollview

Tags: ipad, dynamic, for-loop, scrollview, subviews

I want to remove subviews allocated dynamically in for loop fron scroll view. the code m tryin is:

```
for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.NO_KPI count]; i++) {
static float j = 0;     
roc_temp = [[UIView alloc]init];
roc_temp.frame = CGRectMake(81, 57 + j, 193, 119);
label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label1.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 193, 26);
label1.text = @"Budget";
[roc_temp addsubview:label1];
[scrollview addSubview:roc_temp];

roc_temp1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
roc_temp1.frame = CGRectMake(318, 57 + j, 193, 119);
label11 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label11.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 193, 26);
label11.text = @"Actual";
[roc_temp1 addsubview:label11];
[scrollview addSubview:roc_temp1];
j+=166;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with: you must release your new subviews, as -addSubview: retains them and thus you're causing a memory leak.

To answer: set the "tag" property of the subviews, like this:

```
roc_temp.tag = 1000 * j;
```

and then remove using this code:

```
[[scrollView viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for responding later